# closing my jframe without using the close(X) button and terminating the JVM

Tags: jframe

i have a frame that instantiates another frame but i don't want to use the close(x) button on the instantiated frame., so i created a button. how do i code that this button can be used to close the instantiated frame without quitting the JVM.

Answer (score 5):

Having your own close button is weird UI and should be avoided.

To get rid of a frame when your own button is clicked you can just do:

```
jFrame.setVisible(false);
```

or

```
jFrame.dispose();
```

if you want to get rid of it completely.

On frames you don't want to exit the JVM on the close button being clicked specify:

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

or

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Depending on which of the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
jFrame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setVisible(false)` in order to just hide the instantiated JFrame from view

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom, I think that in the code you wrote down:

```
[framename].setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` means that it will exit the application completely.

You can close the window by clicking on its X button by using:

```
[framename].setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Here is a sample code:

```
package answers;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Answers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //frame 1
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("this is frame 1");
        frame1.setSize(500, 500);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // ignore this its just to place frame 1 on the center

        //now this is the code for frame2
        //frame 2
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("this is frame 2");
        frame2.setSize(500, 500);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the setVisible() or dispose() functions

For your main class...

```
    public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //new DemoTryCatch()
    new Frame1();
}

}
```

For your first frame class...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Frame1 extends JFrame{
JButton newFrame=new JButton("Frame 2");
public Frame1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super("Frame 1");
    add(newFrame);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,300);
    newFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Frame2();\\instantiating your new Frame
        }
    });
}
}
```

For the instantiated frame...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Frame2 extends JFrame{

JButton CloseFrame2=new JButton("CloseFrame2");
public Frame2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super("Frame 1");
    add(CloseFrame2);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,300);
    CloseFrame2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setVisible(false);\\You could also use dispose()
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if im right but you could call `dispose()`. The javadoc suggests you can reopen it though using `show()`.